# Combining two matching Variables in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I´m working with survey data and I have two factor variables in a data frame which are the same measure but for different groups in the experiment. (it was a mistake in the survey.) 
So now I have:

```
df$a1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1)
df$a2 <- c(1, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA)
```

How can i combine those two columns s.t. the values of one fill into the NA's of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could also do:

```
df$combined <- dplyr::coalesce(df$a1, df$a2)
```

Output:

```
  a1 a2 combined
1 NA  1        1
2 NA  1        1
3 NA  0        0
4  1 NA        1
5  0 NA        0
6  1 NA        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R base:

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1), 
                 a2 = c(1, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA))    
df$a_comb <- ifelse(is.na(df$a1), df$a2, df$a1)
df

 a1 a2 a_comb
1 NA  1      1
2 NA  1      1
3 NA  0      0
4  1 NA      1
5  0 NA      0
6  1 NA      1
```